# Does this matrix normal form have a name and has it been used?

Tags: matrices, reference-request

In a research paper in Theoretical Computer Science, we are using a certain matrix normal form, which I was not able to find in the literature (I have to admit that my Linear Algebra got a bit rusty, since I graduated).
This normal form can be considered as a relaxed version of reduced Row Echelon Form which is defined as follows (quotation from Wikipedia):
"
 - All nonzero rows are above any rows of all zeroes.
 - The leading coefficient of a nonzero row is always strictly to the right of the leading coefficient of the row above it.
 - Every leading coefficient is 1 and is the only nonzero entry in its column."

The relaxation is that we do not require that the *leading* coefficient of a nonzero row needs to be the only nonzero entry in its column. We only require that *some* nonzero coefficient of each nonzero row is the only nonzero entry in its column.
I would be grateful for any pointers to the literature regarding this normal form or any normal form "between" reduced Row Echelon Form and "ours".